# 'NoneType' error when using PegasusTokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I tried to use the transformers `PegasusTokenizer` `from_pretrained` method to load the "google/pegasus-large" tokenizer:

```py
from transformers import PegasusTokenizer

tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-large")
```

This raised the following error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

**Important**: I am using a python notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to install `sentencepiece` package and restart the kernel of the python notebook.

```
pip install sentencepiece
```